# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Недопустимый двоичный формат входного потока. Почему возникла данная ошибка?

Tags: c#

```
private void ListenForScreenshots()
        {
            listener.Start();

            while (isListening)
            {
                using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                {
                    using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
                    {
                        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        byte[] screenshotData = (byte[])formatter.Deserialize(ns);

                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(screenshotData))
                        {
                            Image screenshot = Image.FromStream(ms);
                            DisplayScreenshot(screenshot);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            listener.Stop();
        }
```

**Почему возникает ошибка System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Недопустимый двоичный формат входного потока." в этом месте:**

```
byte[] screenshotData = (byte[])formatter.Deserialize(ns);
```

**.net framework 4.8 клиентское и серверное приложение**

Comment: вы делаете что то не то, `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` нужен для того чтобы из байтов восстановить объект класса. Вы же хотите из байтов (в потоке содержаться именно они) получить байты, что это должно значить? Почему нельзя просто считать массив байт и передать его в `MemoryStream`?

Comment: Смотрите ответ по ссылке вверху на дубликат. Если вам не нужно читать и писать с диска, используйте MemoryStream вместо FileStream. Посмотреть больше моих примеров про `TcpListener` можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+tcplistener).